# Nuxt.js footer component is not executing code to retrieve data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

We have a nuxt.js application which retrieves data from strapi. this works for all the other pages that we've created, but when we try to retrieve data for the `<Footer />` it appears that the code is not executing.

This is the code that we use for retrieving on the index page:

```
export default {
   async asyncData({ $strapi }) {
      return {
        homepage: await $strapi.find("homepage"),
      };
   },
}
```

All we change from page to page is the variable name and the value its finding.
This works on 10 - 12 pages.

On main pages we are able to retrieve the data of the footer with this code:

```
export default {
   async asyncData({ $strapi }) {
      return {
        footer: await $strapi.find("footer")
      };
   },
}
```

However when we put this code in our footer component it doesn't appear to execute, as no variable was shown in the view explorer, and if we try an render anything form the {{footer}} then we get an error saying we've referenced something that doesn't exist.

Is there any reason why this code isn't executing in the footer component?

Answer (score 1):

The `asyncData` hook can only be used on page components. The official [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data) explains how you can work around this issue:

> asyncData is only available for pages and you don't have access to this inside the hook.

> 1. Use the new fetch hook that is available in Nuxt 2.12 and later versions.
> 2. Make the API call in the mounted hook and set data properties when loaded. Downside: Won't work for server side rendering.
> 3. Make the API call in the asyncData method of the page component and pass the data as props to the sub components. Server rendering will work fine. Downside: the asyncData of the page might be less readable because it's loading the data for other components.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i'll try this out now :)

Comment: If it resolvers you issue it would be awesome if you mark my answer as correct